# Radio button value vits jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a test form where my radio button have text and value.

I'm trying to pass text from label from checked radio button to hidden field name=form[test]

this is my function:

```
    var levels = $('input[name="form[Button]"]:checked + label').map(function() {
return $(this).text();
}).get();

$('input[name="form[test]"]').change( function() {
($(this).val(levels));
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="Button0" value="0" name="form[Button]">
<label for="Button0">This item is worth £0</label>
<input type="radio" id="Button1" value="100" name="form[Button]">
<label for="Button0">This item is worth £100</label>

<input type="hidden" value="" id="test" name="form[test]">
```

But my change in jQuery simply dont work.

Many Thanks for your help in advance!

Dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[name="form[Button]"]').change(function() {
    var level = $('input:radio[name="form[Button]"]:checked + label').text();
    $('input[name="form[test]"]').val(level);
});
```

And you can see a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7aYzq/2/).

Comment: The label's text isn't likely to change over time, then why would you repeatedly query for it?

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$('input[name="form[Button]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).data('label', $(this).next('label').text());
});

$('input[name="form[Button]"]').change(function() {
    $('input[name="form[test]"]').val($(this).data('label'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$('input[name="form[test]"]').change( function() {
($(this).val(levels));
});
```

means that you only want to change the value of the hidden input when it already changes by some other influence. I think you mean:

```
var levels = $('input[name="form[Button]"]:checked + label').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

$('input[name="form[test]"]').val(levels);
```